# use js variable in html

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I get some wierd error (Express 400 Error: Bad Request)

some lines is traslated to the variable value and some just outputs as an error.

this is an example of my code

```
exports.add_comment = function(req, res){

  var id = req.params.id;

  req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

    connection.query('Select * from Campgrounds where campID = ?', [id], function(err, rows){
      if (err) {
       console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.render('add_comment',{page_title:"Add Comment", data:rows});
      }
    });
  });
};


exports.save_comment = function(req,res){

  var id = req.params.id;
  var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));

  req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
   connection.query('Select * from Campgrounds where campID = ?', [id], function(err, rows){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      var test = '<%= data[i].campID %>';
      res.redirect("/campgrounds/show/" + test);
    } else {
      var data = {

        campID      : rows[0].campID,
        comment     : input.content,
        camper      : input.camper
      };

      connection.query('INSERT INTO Comments set ?', data, function(err, rows)
      {

        if (err)
          console.log("Error inserting : %s ",err );

          res.redirect("/campgrounds/show/<%=rows[0].campID%>");

      });
    }

   });
 });
};
```

and thats the ejs file -  add_comment.ejs

```
<%- include layouts/header.ejs %>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-xm-offset-3">
    <div class="well">
      <h2 class="text-center">Add new Comment</h2>   <p><%=data[0].campID%></p>
      <form method="post" action="/campgrounds/show/<%=data[0].campID%>/comments/add">
          <div class="form-group" style="margin: 10%;">
            <label>Content</label>
            <input type="textarea" name="content" class="form-control input-lg" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" style="margin: 10%;">
            <label>camper</label>
            <input type="text" name="camper" class="form-control input-lg" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" style="margin: 10%; margin-bottom: 15px;">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" >Submit</button>
          </div>
      </form>
      <p style="margin: 10%; margin-top: 0px;"><a href="/campgrounds/show/<%=data[0].campID%>">Go back!</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<%- include layouts/footer.ejs %>
```

Now when i start the server, the "Go back" button for example does work and translates `href="..<%=data[0].campID%>"` to campID value (2)

and when i use submit button the same `<%=data[0].campID%>` becomes `"%3C%=rows[0].campID%%3E"` instead of the value.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I think in your js you have to do

`res.redirect("/campgrounds/show/" + rows[0].campID);`

Instead of

`res.redirect("/campgrounds/show/<%=rows[0].campID%>");`

The syntax you use in your html templates is generally going to be different than what you use for your js.